# VideoJS Swf Remove Right Click Menu

Tags: actionscript-3, video.js

i want disabling context menu , i never worked with actionscript , after some search i find this code for disabling context menu :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});

Mouse.hide();
```

i want know how can apply it in VideoJS.as.

Here is source code in ActionScript https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/tree/master/src

Comment: How do you use the VideoJS class in your project? Do you want to adjust VideoJS.as or in your project code?

Comment: @FrédericCox i am using `grunt mxmlc` and compile SWF file.

Comment: But how do you instantiate the VideoJS class in your code? If you do something like var videoJS:VideoJS = new VideoJS(); then after that add the eventlisteners for rightClick and contextMenu and use evt.preventDefault or set an empty custom contextMenu. That might work. If you have a code sample that would help

Answer (score 0):

> *"I find this code for disabling context menu... I want know how can apply it in `VideoJS.as`"*.

Open [**`VideoJS.as`**](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/master/src/VideoJS.as)... Find the following  code (line 57 onwards):

> ```
>   // add content-menu version info
>
>   var _ctxVersion:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("VideoJS Flash Component v" + VERSION, false, false);
>   var _ctxAbout:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Copyright © 2014 Brightcove, Inc.", false, false);
>   var _ctxMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
>   _ctxMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
>   _ctxMenu.customItems.push(_ctxVersion, _ctxAbout);
>   this.contextMenu = _ctxMenu;
> ```

Change it to become

```
// add content-menu version info

/*
var _ctxVersion:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("VideoJS Flash Component v" + VERSION, false, false);
var _ctxAbout:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Copyright © 2014 Brightcove, Inc.", false, false);
var _ctxMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
_ctxMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
_ctxMenu.customItems.push(_ctxVersion, _ctxAbout);
this.contextMenu = _ctxMenu;
*/

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
```

Now try compiling a new SWF output of VideoJS. If it worked correctly there should be no response when right-clicking. Above code is untested (no time) but it's the correct code logic.

Let me know if it's a working solution.

Comment: I tested the code. It works fine. So you have a correct answer to your Question, since regarding where to change code in the `.as` file. Please mark it as solved and ask a new Question about any further issues (your **new error** is to do with your MXMLC compiler settings, nothing wrong with my answer or Video-JS)...

Comment: You are getting those errors because AS3 updates for allowing `CONTEXT_MENU` & `RIGHT_CLICK` were added to FlashPlayer **11.2** onwards. Likely your compiler is making output (swf) for older Flash Player versions. **I tested this** with Flash IDE and I get exact same error **only if** I choose to output to some older SWF version (ie: version **10.1**). I don't use `Grunt MXMLC` but if it uses the FLEX SDK just go to its install folder and find these folders... `Frameworks\Libs\Player` now in that `Player` folder what do you see? (should be a sub-folder with Flash Player version as name).